# How to solve problem with responsive layout?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I have problem, I use this piece of code to responsive layout. In my computer when I use programming tools to watch how my code look in phone size, it look perfect but when I deployment it this not work at all.
I do not understand why, because I have the same piece of code in another sub-page, and there it work good.

```
import MediaQuery, { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";

    const Phone = useMediaQuery({
      query: "(max-width: 641px)"
    });
    <Card style={{ width: Phone ? '100%' : "32%", float: "left", backgroundColor: "#003263", height: "380px"}} >
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem, I searched for several solutions, but I ended up using material UI.

```js
import React from 'react'
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery'


const ProductCard = ({ name, category, description, tech, url, image, color }) => {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 786px)')

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: isMobile ? '0px' : '18px' }}>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>{category}...</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductCard
```

It worked perfect, on mobile in the first render it detects the variable correctly and makes the css change, but you would have to install MUI